# UIActivityIndicatorView NSURLConnection, view not showing

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, uiactivityindicatorview

I have a problem getting a UIActivityIndicatorView to show when I collect data from a server with help from the NSURLConnection request.

The request I think is asynchronous, i.e., started in a new thread. I have copied from Apple's AdvancedTableViewCells example. And I run it in XCode in the iOS 4.3 iPhone simulator. I have not tested it on a real iPhone yet.

Also I have googled this problem and tried a lot of suggestions but the feeling is that I have forgotten something basic. Below is  my code from the class RootViewController.

I just select a row, create and add the activityview, startanimating, and then create the NSUrlConnection object which starts to fetch data from the server in another thread, I believe.

Any ideas?

```
@interface RootViewController : UITableViewController {
    NSMutableData *receivedData;
    UIActivityIndicatorView *activityView;
}

@end

...

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // In my rootviewcontroller
    activityView = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];

    [self.view addSubview:activityView];
    [activityView startAnimating];
    …

    NSMutableURLRequest *tUrlRequest = [tQuery createUrlRequest:tStatId];
    NSURLConnection *tConnectionResponse = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest: tUrlRequest delegate: self];

    if (!tConnectionResponse) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to submit request");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Request submitted");
        receivedData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
    }
    return;
}

...

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

    NSLog(@"Succeeded! Received %d bytes of data",[receivedData length]);

    NSXMLParser *tParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData: receivedData];
    ...

    [tParser parse]; 
    ...

    [connection release];
    [receivedData release];

    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval: 2.0]; // Just to see if activity view will show up...

    NSUInteger row = 1;  
    if (row != NSNotFound) 
    { 
        // Create the view controller and initialize it with the 
        // next level of data. 
        VivadataTViewController *vivaViewController = [[VivadataTViewController alloc] init];

        if (activityView != nil) {
            [activityView stopAnimating];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry... it was white avtivityview on a white background. Terribly sorry.

Comment: it's cool that you solved it. however if you answer your own question and accept the answer, thread will be marked as "answered" and others may benefit from it as well.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same exact issue, try to change the color of the **UIActivityIndicatorView** under **Attributes Inspector** -> **Style** to **Gray**

[image]